# debian mate desktop environnment time problem

Tags: time, display-settings

I have mate environment and impossible to set up the time ... the time is set 5 hours later, and I set the time + time zone but the time stays like it..
idea how to change it?
thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following command:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Time/Zone
```

or:

```
sudo  dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

e,g:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
```

To list time zones:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```